# Best way to make system (stock) app

Tags: android

Here's the scenario. I have been asked to make an application which requires several system app only permissions. This is because the tablet is going to be used by employees and it needs to be locked down ect.
Is there is a programmatic way install a system app instead of installing it as a user app? If not what is the best way to make and install the system app to the tablet without rooting it if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to root it.  To be a system app, you need to be installed with the OS or as part of an OS update.  That's the entire point of being a system app-  the user can't have installed it.  You'll need to root the device to put it on.